# Capture nested <canvas> tags with HTML2Canvas

Tags: javascript, html, html2canvas

I'm wondering - using Html2Canvas if I capture a containing `<div>` then is there a way to also include a nested `<canvas>` tag within said div?

I have my capture working but there is essentially a gap where the nested canvas sits on-screen.

```
<div id="my-container">
   <h2>my title</h2>
   <p>Some other content here</p>
   <canvas id="existing-canvas" height="270" style="height:270px;"></canvas>
   <p>Some more content</p>
</div>

<script>
html2canvas(document.getElementById("my-container")).then(function(canvas) {
    var dataUrl = canvas.toDataURL();
    //do something with the base64 image data here...
</script>
```

### Update: Issue found

This is a timing issue on my part. The nested canvas element in question is saved but i'm doing so before its contents have been rendered to the DOM.

Comment: canvas is not a void element and a closing tag `</canvas>` must be present. Not sure it is the cause of what you describe though, since there is nothing in you code that would make the canvas non empty anyway. Please provide an [mcve].

Comment: a typo. i've added the closing tag.

Comment: Issue found - this is a timing issue on my part. The nested canvas element in question is saved but i'm doing so before its contents have been rendered to the DOM.